# Angular 4 - Scroll To item in list based on search input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, search

I can do this with custom javascript but was wondering if there is anything built into Angular 4 that I might be able to make use of.  I have a list of checkboxes that can be scrolled through and a search input above.  I want to be able to jump to a section in the list as a user types in the search input. My HTML:

```
<!-- Sold To -->
<div class="col-md-12 input-container">
    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Jump to Soldto...">
        <div class="checkbox-wrap">
            <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let option of soldToOptions">
                {{ option }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a sample list of the array that I am looping through for the checkboxes (there will actually be about 300 entries in this array)...

```
soldToOptions = [ 
 '1028341000-MITSUBISHI WONOKE MENTOR-DALLAS',
 '1018551000-ADVANCE STARTER TEST-CINCINNATI',
 '1030591000-AMERICAN JOYRIDE CARTHAGE-SAN FRANCISCO',
 '1023221000-TESTING GENERAL OAKLAND-OAKLAND' 
];
```

I will first need to order these alphabetically based on the the first part of the string after the initial '-'.  Just wondering if there is anything built in to Angular 4 that would allow me to match the user's input string to the value from the array and jump to that section in the scrollable checkboxes.  I strictly do not want to filter the list, just move the the proper place in the list. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[ngx-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll) should be able to meet your needs. You would just need a way to dynamically add the markup to identify each element generated.